# What is the state-of-the-art approach to testing jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

I'm new to JavaScript. Imagine, I have following piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nights').on('keyup', function() {
    var nights = +$(this).val();
    var dailyPrice = +$(this).closest(".tour").data("daily-price");
    $('#total').text(nights * dailyPrice);
    $('#nights-count').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

How can I unit-test that the anonymous function

1. retrieves the value of the current element,
2. retrieves the data from `+$(this).closest(".tour").data("daily-price")` and
3. then calls `text(...)` on `$('#total')` and `$('#nights-count')`

?

Note that I'm interested in *unit* tests (therefore creating a full-fledged a Selenium test suite, which types in something and then checks the value of the elements isn't suitable for me), which don't require me to add a new abstraction layer.

By *abstraction layer* I mean this: I could create class `JQueryAbstraction` and then 2 sub-classes - one, which calls real jQuery methods and another, which just counts the number of calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try introducing the popular Unit Testing lightweight frameworks like Jasmine, Mocha, QUnit

All these framework can co-exist with AngularJS, JQuery....etc

From your example, which you are trying with an anonymous function, you can convert that function to a non-anonymous function and pass it to the testing tool

to make sure the last line is reached I am introducing a simple global variable and assigning value to it, say done = true or done = false

Example:

```
var done = false;
var onReady = function() {
  $('#nights').on('keyup', function() {
    var nights = +$(this).val();
    var dailyPrice = +$(this).closest(".tour").data("daily-price");
    $('#total').text(nights * dailyPrice);
    $('#nights-count').text($(this).val());
  });
  done = true;
}

$(document).ready(onReady);
```

So now you can test your **onReady** code with unit testing as in Jasmine, you can comment the actual document ready

```
//$(document).ready(onReady);
```

And call the function via unit testing

```
describe("Document Ready Unit Testing", function() {
  it("call the function ", function() {
     done = false;
     onReady() ;
     expect(done).toEqual(true);//this will print the unit testing passed or failed
  });
});
```

**But:** If you are not interested in declaring the anonymous function separately then you can loop through the **document** object and get the ready event function.